# Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Using OmniAuth (with omniauth_crowd), I'd like user to be redirected back to the login page if he doesn't submit right username and password. It works fine in production, but I have annoying problem testing it.

To mock OmniAuth provider, I use the following code, as recommended by the author of OmniAuth plugin:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:someProvider] = :invalid_credentials
visit_page @page
```

The code above automatically (i.e. without entering username and password) redirects Capybara to the `session#failure`. My `session#failure` redirects to the `login_path`.

Thus I end up in a loop:

```
redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects. (Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError)
```

What is the best workaround for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a simular issue with Omniauth.
Not sure if there is a workaround, since it is the way `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth` works.

My solution was to use `fakeweb` instead of the OmniAuth mocking.
You should probably start off by looking at how omniauth_crowd is tested itself.
Here is a good example:
https://github.com/robdimarco/omniauth_crowd/blob/master/spec/omniauth/strategies/crowd_spec.rb#L49-69